# CLI log screen for USB to serial in ubuntu 16.04 is not working

Tags: 16.04, command-line, usb, log

Connected serial to USB in ubuntu 16.04. and it is listed in my cli like ttyUSB0

While opening the screen using `screen -L /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` it is not opening the log screen from serial device. It remains the same. 
i ran `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get update` but they are not helping.

Can anyone solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall solved the issue. Uninstall it first.

```
apt remove screen && apt purge screen
```

the reinstall again

```
apt install screen
```